# How to understand the data structure of a multi-index series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm going over the book 'Python for Data Analysis' by Wes Mckinney. At one point, we have this:

```
by_tz_os = cframe.groupby(['tz', operating_system])
agg_counts = by_tz_os.size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

I tried to understand the structure of series *by_tz_os.size()* by:

```
print 'Name is:', by_tz_os.size().name 
print 'Index is:', by_tz_os.size().index.name 
print by_tz_os.size()[:5]
```

Here is result:

```
Name is: None 
Index is: None 

tz                            
                  Not Windows     245
                  Windows         276
Africa/Cairo      Windows          3
Africa/Casablanca Windows          1
Africa/Ceuta      Windows          2
dtype: int64
```

What are these 3 columns (col1,col2,col3, let's say) in series context?  I'm thinking col1 & col2 are index, but that's not the case from the result above. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `DataFrame.groupby().size()` is explained [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation). The relevant part:

> Another simple aggregation example is to compute the size of each
>   group. This is included in GroupBy as the size method. It returns a
>   Series whose index are the group names and whose values are the sizes
>   of each group.
>
> ```
> In [54]: grouped.size()
> Out[54]: 
> A    B    
> bar  one      1
>      three    1
>      two      1
> foo  one      2
>      three    1
>      two      2
> dtype: int64
> ```

Regarding

```
print 'Name is:', by_tz_os.size().name
print 'Index is:', by_tz_os.size().index.name
```

yielding

```
Name is: None 
Index is: None
```

As you already mentioned, `by_tz_os.size()` is a Series. Unlike with, for example, the `cframe["tz"]` Series for which the `name` attribute will be set to "tz", `by_tz_os.size()` does not have a name attached to it, most probably due to there being no obvious way to name groupby() results in general. Which is, of course, why `by_tz_os.size().name` is `None` here.

`by_tz_os.size().index.name` returns a `None` simply due to the index being a MultiIndex. You are expected to use `names` instead (which works with both the normal Index and the MultiIndex, by the way).

Comment: Good example Martin. I think I get the idea.  by_tz_os.size().index actually shows the index details.  I checked it on your example and the my example.  I wonder what series.index.name does.  I just want to print the names.  For your case, I want to just print the names (A & B) without the actual keys (bar, foo).

Comment: Missed that part of your question, sorry. I expanded my answer with an explanation about the `name` attributes being `None`s.